# Workaround for samesite cookies in identity used in .net core 1.x

Tags: cookies, .net-core, identityserver4, samesite

Hi I have a project implemented .in net core 1.0 with identity. Now facing issue on login in chrome 84.x version due to same site cookie policy.
Is there any workaround available to fix this issue without migrating to latest core version.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple ASP.NET Middleware that inspects the responses and rewrites the SET-Cookie statements and fix the samesite attribute....

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1